# How to multi-thread this?

Tags: c++, pthreads, mutex, condition-variable

I wish to have two threads.  The first thread1 occasionally calls the following pseudo function:

```
void waitForThread2() {
  if (thread2 is not idle) {
    return;
  }
  notifyThread2IamReady(); // i.e. via 1st condition variable
  Wait for thread2 to finish exclusive access. // i.e. via 2nd condition variable.
}
```

The second thread2 is forever in the following pseudo loop:

```
for (;;) {
  Notify thread1 I am idle.
  Wait for thread1 to be ready. // i.e. via 1st condition variable.
  Notify thread1 I am exclusive.
  Do some work while thread1 is blocked.
  Notify thread1 I am busy. // i.e. via 2nd condition variable.
  Do some work in parallel with thread1.
}
```

What is the best way to write this such that both thread1 and thread2 are kept as busy as possible on a machine with multiple cores.  I would like to avoid long delays between notification in one thread and detection by the other.  I tried using pthread condition variables but found the delay between thread2 doing 'notify thread1 I am busy' and the loop in waitForThread2() on thear2IsExclusive() can be up to almost one second delay.  I then tried using a volatile sig_atomic_t shared variable to control the same, but something is going wrong, so I must not be doing it correctly.

Comment: you would be better off telling people the problem you are actually trying to solve, rather than asking them to implement a solution you have already conceived...

Comment: Your pseudocode doesn't make much sense.  How do you notify another thread you are busy and why?  Also, you're focusing on threads here; typically, you need to synchronize data.  What data are you synchronizing, and how are your operations on it in parallel?

Comment: You're doing something very wrong if your condvars are taking a second to do anything. Moreover, the canonical thing to do is to hold a lock on a data structure, not "notify another thread"; the latter does not scale.

Comment: @tc Most of the time the cond var is fast, but occasionally it can take up to close to a second.

Comment: @WhirlWind The work in parallel is on separate data, and thus need not be synchronized.  Currently, I notify the other thread I am busy via condition variables.  They reason to notify is because during the short busy period, thread2 is modifying the data structures looked at by thread1.

Comment: Well, that's a complete misuse of a condition variable, but I think this is beyond help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looks to me like you are trying to do a rendezvous (a term from Ada).

The second thread is sitting, waiting for the first thread to call it, then it does some work immediately while the first thread waits, and some more work after the first thread is finished.

The first thread is "calling" the second thread - with an immediate timeout if the second thread is unavailable to take the call.

Ada supports this directly in the language, but assuming that porting to Ada isn't an option...

This could be implemented with three semaphores. Semaphore 1 indicates that thread 1 is ready to rendezvous. Semaphore 2 indicates thread 2 is ready to rendevous. Semaphore 3 indicates the rendezvous is complete.

Thread 1: Defaults with Semaphore 1 acquired.

```
 if Semaphore 2.acquire(timeout = 0) is successful # Thread 2 is ready
     Semaphore 1.release() # Indicate I am ready
     Semaphore 3.acquire() # Wait until the rendevous is complete.
     Semaphore 3.release()
     Semaphore 1.acquire() # Indicate I am not ready
     Semaphore 2.release() # I am no longer using thread 2.

 Do concurrent work
```

Thread 2: Defaults with Semaphore 2 acquired.

```
 Loop forever
     Semaphore 3.acquire() # Indicate Rendevous is not complete.
     Semaphore_2.release() # Indicate I am ready
     Semaphore_1.acquire() # Wait for Thread 1 to be ready
     Joint processing
     Semaphore 1.release() # I am no longer using thread 1.
     Semaphore 3.release() # Rendevous is complete.
     Semaphore 2.acquire() # I am not ready

 Post-processing
```

NOTE: Written from scratch, not tested. Looks a lot more complicated than I thought it would be when I started; have I missed something?

Comment: Is a semaphore more efficient than using condition variables with mutex locks?

Comment: More efficient in lines of code? Dunno. More efficient at run-time? I doubt you could tell the difference, compared to all the other overheads. I'll be very surprised if there aren't many better places in your code to optimise.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you should be using semaphores for signalling, rather than having "while" loops that idle the threads, waiting for some condition to occur.  Idle loops are bad.

Comment: Idle loop was really to explain the idea, not to really be implemented that way.  I've removed them from the question since they were causing distraction from the main question. Presently, those are implemented with condition variables with no timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than having your threads tell each other "I'm busy" or "I'm not busy", try to think in terms of the data objects your threads are operating on.

If there's some data (say, a counter) that both threads may try to alter simultaneously, that means you need a mutex there.

When a thread makes a change to the shared data state that other threads might be waiting for, signal a condition variable to notify them. (For example, if a Producer thread adds data to a queue, it might signal the "dataAvailable" condition, which a Consumer could be waiting on.)

Comment: I think that's the heart of the issue.